# Using existing Dynamic Distribution List as Security Group

Tags: office365

I wanted to use my existing Dynamic Distribution Group as Security Group. Other than to use the same group to send mass emails, I also want to use it to share and give permissions to my Calendar.

Is there a way to use the existing DDL as Security Group so i can share/assign permission?

By the way, I am currently using Office 365 portal to create/manage my Dynamic Distribution Group.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have made statements of fact. What is your question?

Comment: Sorry guys, 

forgot to include this fact: You cannot use Dynamic Distribution List to assign/share permission.

forgot to include this question : Is there a way to use the existing DDL as Security Group so i can share/assign permission?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is no.  I don't see a way to convert an existing group from one type to another in Azure AD.